# Eclipse project explorer prefixing latex project names with "P/"

Tags: eclipse, latex

Okay, this has been bugging me for quite some time today : Eclipse's Project Explorer adds a prefix "P/" to some of my projects' name. It happens only in the explorer, as everywhere else the project name appears normally.

I didn't manage to find anything relevant on the subject in the doc' and I don't really know how to google it.

I just reinstalled Eclipse's Platform Binary 3.7.2 along with the CDT and Texlipse plugins on Precise. The prefix "P/" appears only with texlipse projects, or when I open a .tex file inside any project.

So my question is : do you know what it means ? How to get rid or it ?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `toString()` on a `Project` you get this. The leading `P/` indicates it's a project (it's a convention of all of the Eclipse resources, `F/` for file for example). This is probably a problem in the Texlipse plugin where the label provider that they provide to the Project Explorer (Common Nagivgator) is wrong, it's using just the project, instead of `project.getName()`. You should file a bug with them. There is nothing that you can do about it as a user.